# stopping a C# timer and callback executed

Tags: c#

I am start using C# `System.Threading.Timer` class. When the timer is already started and I am in the middle of the execution of my TimerCallback I specified, what does happen when I stop the timer using `myTimer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0)`.

My callback finishes execution or it is aborted immediately?

If it is not aborted there is a way to perform something similar to `Thread.Abort` for the immediate killing of the code to execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callback is not aborted, it finishes execution.
If you want to stop executing, simply `return` from the function.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `System.Timers.Timer`, and you will have to check for the Enabled property of the timer in the callback function to stop execution.

Example:

```
using System.Timers;
```

Create a new Timer object:

```
Timer timerObject = new Timer();
timerObject.Interval = 1000;
timerObject.Start();
timerObject.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timerObject_Elapsed);
```

And in the event handlign function check for Enabled:

```
void timerObject_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Timer timerObject = (Timer)sender;
    if (!timerObject.Enabled) return;
    while(true)
    {
        DoSomething.....
        if (!timerObject.Enabled) return;
    }
}
```